# Metasploit msfconsole method_missing on Fedora 19

Tags: ruby, fedora, metasploit

I installed metasploit on my Fedora 19 using [this guide from fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Metasploit).  After finishing all the steps I run *msfconsole* and get the following error:

`/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/specification.rb:1888:in 'method_missing': undefined local variable or method 'ext_dir' for #<Gem::Specification:0xecbd78 json-1.8.0> (NameError)
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:42:in 'load_paths'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:37:in 'block in setup'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in .setup'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler.rb:120:in 'setup'
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in ''top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in 'require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in 'rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in 'require'
    from /opt/metasploit/msf/lib/fastlib.rb:374:in 'require'
    from /opt/metasploit/msf/lib/msfenv.rb:7:in '<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from /opt/metasploit/msf/lib/fastlib.rb:374:in 'require'
    from /usr/local/bin/msfconsole:21:in '<main>'`

Any ideas how to fix this?  It says method_missing: undefined local variable or method "ext_dir" so this looks like some kind of Ruby dependency issue.

Update:  *msfupdate* runs successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running a 64bit version of fedora? If so I would suggest you download the packages from rapid7 website. Its more dependable, and when installed any dependency issues will be resolved. With 64bt linux you can also couple metasploit with Nexpose their free scanner. These two tools work hand in hand. The issue you are seeing looks like a version problem. If you don't mind running a VM I would suggest you download Kali linux for your security testing needs which will work out of the box + give you a ton more tools.

Comment: That works just fine!  I was not aware that they had a Linux installer and assumed it had to be installed manually.