# Running RoR on Fedora, get: undefined local variable or method `ext_dir' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedora

I'm trying to install [Catarse.me](https://github.com/catarse/catarse) on a Fedora 19 machine, ready to be pushed to Heroku.

I've managed to successfully run bundle install. But when I try

```
rake db:migrate
```

I receive this error

```
[root@acer]$ rake db:migrate 
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `ext_dir' for #<Gem::Specification:0x450c8ce RedCloth-4.2.9>
/home/user/rails/catarse/config/boot.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/rails/catarse/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/rails/catarse/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've individually checked each of these files, and on the lines noted there's a call to

```
variablename = File.expand_path('../path/to/Gemfile', __FILE__)
```

CORRECTION The stack trace points to line 7 in book.rb

```
Bundler.setup
```

I've googled but the only relevant hit is [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433888/metasploit-msfconsole-method-missing-on-fedora-19) but whose situation and answer is unrelated to my problem.

I'd appreciate the help.

Running `rake db:migrate -- trace` gives

```
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `ext_dir' for #<Gem::Specification:0x4700158 RedCloth-4.2.9>
/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/specification.rb:1887:in `method_missing'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:42:in `load_paths'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:37:in `block in setup'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.1/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
/home/mei/rails/catarse/config/boot.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/mei/rails/catarse/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/mei/rails/catarse/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please run it with a trace as specified on the last line of the error

Comment: @Mike86 OK, just posted it. seems like a problem with the Bundler gem?

Comment: Gem update bundler -- lemme know if it helped (though i think you've got the latest version)

Comment: @Mike86 it updated to v1.3.5, seems to have done the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem. I've posted it as the answer for future reference, please choose it if it helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your trace, it seems like it's a bundler issue,

running

```
gem update bundler
```

should fix it.